# Simulating app from flutter on my Mi A1 not woking

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is part of my main dart code ,

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appbar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Personal Expenses'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              _startAddNewTransaction(context);
            }) 
      ],
    );
return Scaffold(
      appBar: appbar,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        appbar.preferredSize.height -
                        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                    0.4,
                child: Chart(_recetTransactions)),
            Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        appbar.preferredSize.height -
                        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                    0.6,
                child: TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            _startAddNewTransaction(context);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**when i use dynamic height this shows the app not loading**

D/OpenGLRenderer(20329): Skia GL Pipeline

W/example.NewApp(20329): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J (light greylist, reflection)

W/example.NewApp(20329): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J (light greylist, reflection)

W/example.NewApp(20329): Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray; (light greylist, reflection)

W/example.NewApp(20329): Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J (light greylist, reflection)

I/OpenGLRenderer(20329): Initialized EGL, version 1.4

D/OpenGLRenderer(20329): Swap behavior 2

D/vndksupport(20329): Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.

D/vndksupport(20329): Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.

Comment: One issue I can see in the second line is that appBar: appbar.
It should be appBar: AppBar(), as appbar is not a widget.

Comment: You mean dynamic height for Container widget?

Comment: using as a object here

Comment: yes both the widgets ,